# How to change hostname in Odin?

Tags: settings, system

Tried "sudo su" then "nano /etc/hostname" I dont seem to find a way to save that. Ctrl+O change options at the bottom. Now, I have other options but not sure how to exit after actually saving it. It's not saved as hostname is the same after reboot as before.

Answer (score 1):

To change your hostname, run the command below.

```
hostnamectl set-hostname "hostname"
```

Comment: I'll try that in the evening. Thank you.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot, Emrys.

Comment: No problem, eSolus!